# How to wait for some fixed amount of bytes in a node.js stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a node.js Readable stream and I want to read the first 20 bytes and do some processing with them, setting a callback for the processed data or receiving a promise.

Is there any function built in node or elsewhere in NPM to do that?

For example, it could look something like this:

```
var stream = getStreamSomehow();
readPromise(stream, 20)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("I have read 20 bytes! %s", data.toString());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this with node core is by calling `stream.read(20)`, checking if the return value is `null` and if so, listen for the `readable` event before trying to `stream.read(20)` again. Otherwise if the return is not null, it's a 20-byte Buffer containing data from the stream.

Comment: Why? There may only be 10 bytes available ofter the `readable` event. In that case `.read(20)` will still return `null`.

Comment: Sure, that's possible I suppose. Then you just listen for `readable` again.

Comment: Looks like the stream will adjust it's highwatermark to the size of the last read