# Read exactly n bytes asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stream

I am working on a node.js project. Is it possible to read exactly `n` bytes asynchronously from a stream?

Usually, if I want to read a stream asynchronously, I use events. The problem is that I need to process the rest of the stream asynchronously, too.

If I listen for the `data` event, I can use the rest of the stream later, but I cannot control how many bytes I want to read at once. I tried to use `unshift` to put the unused bytes back into the buffer but this does not seem to fire the `data` event when another listener is added later.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461310/) is similar, but the only answer is a synchronous solution.

Is there an option to limit the number of bytes being passed to the `data` event listeners? Is it possible to somehow push the bytes back into the stream and still make them accessible through events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're listening to the `readable` event and not doing a blocking look calling `stream.read(n);`, then that solution is asynchronous. Something like the following (untested!) should get you what you want.

```
function streamChunk(stream, size, dataCallback, doneCallback) {
  function getChunk() {
    var data = stream.read(size);
    if(data != null) {
      dataCallback(data);
      setImmediate(getChunk);
    }
  }

  stream.on('readable', getChunk);
  stream.on('end', doneCallback);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this a few minutes ago when I read the node docs again. My implementation is a little different and I think you should add `removeListener` after getting the data.

Comment: Why would you do that? According to the docs: *Once the internal buffer is drained, a readable event will fire again when more data is available.* So it shouldn't fire off another readable until you've `stream.read` all the buffered data. http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable

Comment: @timotystrimple That situation is possible, isn't it? Imagine another piece of code that drains the buffer later, and another `readable` event is emitted, so your listener will read the data again. Am I wrong?

Comment: You mean a different stream, or multiple `readable` events on a single stream? If it's the later, that's by design. The `readable` event isn't necessarily called when **all** data is ready to be read, but when **some** data is ready. You should get multiple `readable` event calls per stream, and you rely on the `end` event to know you're done.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought your function should implement my requirements. As it is, it is fine. Thank you! (I actually only need to read the first 128 bits before switching to streaming mode)

Comment: what if the on "readable" is called but there isn't *size* bytes of data available yet, but a smaller amount?